Very low quality accepted answers
How do we deal with very low quality answers such as https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/20032 when it seems you cannot flag the answer as low quality.  I assume I can't flag it because the answer is accepted?

I'm curious as well...I think the solution is probably to simply downvote. I think this might be one of the weaknesses of the SE model for scientific stacks. In StackOverflow, if an asker deems an answer sufficient to solve their problem, it makes sense to make it as accepted. In the context of science, you might have two people in an asker and answerer who know nothing about what they are talking about and yet they agree on some falsehood.

I have made another attempt to flag the question as 'very low quality and managed to do this.  I don't know if there was a time lock on flagging in this manner but it should show in review queues now.  The answerer has stated they cannot provide direct references.

You should see politics.SE. Accepted answers with -10 overall score. Below that an answer with +15 overall score. Such are the limits of the SE model applied to less-than-hard topics areas.

Also, the interpretation of the low quality flag varies extremely between sites. On some only absolute gibberish (like totally random characters) is accepted by the mods as a correct application of the low quality flag.

Related: What to do with bad accepted answers
